# My xsl stylesheet generates an xml file with multiple roots

Tags: java, xslt

I have a problem in parsing xml files with xslt stylesheets
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html
i changed a bit in the stylizer code to input more than one xml file
(( just to give you a good background ))

everything is working perfectly BUT the root is mutiplied !

this is my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 extension-element-prefixes="exsl" version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
 <request campus="UQU" year="2013" term="second">
 <xsl:for-each select="/SIS_REP070/LIST_G_STUDENT_ID/G_STUDENT_ID">
 .
 .
 .
 <xsl:for-each select="document('sis_rep413b_anon.xml')/MODULE1/LIST_G_STUDENT_ID/G_STUDENT_ID[STUDENT_ID=$varID]">
 .
 .
 .
 <xsl:for-each select="document('sis_rep814.xml')/SIS_REP814/LIST_DEGREE_PLANS/DEGREE_PLANS[EDITION1=57][TOTAL_HRS=160]/LIST_G_COURSE_LEVEL/G_COURSE_LEVEL/LIST_G_COURSE_CODE/G_COURSE_CODE">
 .
 .
 .
 </xsl:for-each>
 </request>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see i am implementing this stylesheet on several xmls

so the root is outputed x times ( x= xml input files )

this is what the output looks like :

```
 <request campus="UQU" year="2013" term="second">

 <student key="42701646">
 <name first="فؤاد" last="خوج"/><MAX>0</MAX>
 <acadArea abbv="CSandISG"><major code="143100"/></acadArea>

 <updateCourseRequests commit="true">
 <courseOffering1 subjectArea="RELg" courseNumber="16312012" priority="19981.921" credit="2"/>
  </updateCourseRequests></student>
  .
  .
  .
  .
   </request>
   <request campus="UQU" year="2013" term="second"/>
   <request campus="UQU" year="2013" term="second"/>
   <request campus="UQU" year="2013" term="second"/>
```

The root "request" is printed three more times !:(
Because i entered four xml files 
This is the command i wrote in the command prompt :

```
java Stylizer data/file1.xsl data/file1.xml data/file2.xml data/file3.xml data/file4.xml
```

THE ORIGINAL STYLIZER:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;

// For write operation
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;


public class Stylizer {
// Global value so it can be ref'd by the tree-adapter
static Document document;

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    if (argv.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java Stylizer stylesheet xmlfile");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    //factory.setValidating(true);
    try {
        File stylesheet = new File(argv[0]);
        File datafile = new File(argv[1]);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.parse(datafile);

        // Use a Transformer for output
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
        // Error generated by the parser
        System.out.println("\n** Transformer Factory error");
        System.out.println("   " + tce.getMessage());

        // Use the contained exception, if any
        Throwable x = tce;

        if (tce.getException() != null) {
            x = tce.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        // Error generated by the parser
        System.out.println("\n** Transformation error");
        System.out.println("   " + te.getMessage());

        // Use the contained exception, if any
        Throwable x = te;

        if (te.getException() != null) {
            x = te.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sxe) {
        // Error generated by this application
        // (or a parser-initialization error)
        Exception x = sxe;

        if (sxe.getException() != null) {
            x = sxe.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        // Parser with specified options can't be built
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // I/O error
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} // main
}
```

AFTER MY MODIFICATION :

```
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError;
 import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;

 // For write operation
 import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
 import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
 import java.io.*;


public class Stylizer {


public static void main(String[] argv) {
    if (argv.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java Stylizer stylesheet xmlfile");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    //factory.setValidating(true);
    try {
        File stylesheet = new File(argv[0]);
        File [] fileList = new File[argv.length];

        for(int i=1 ; i<argv.length ; i++)
            fileList[i] = new File(argv[i]);

        String targetExtension = ".xml";  
        int extIndex = argv[0].lastIndexOf(".");  
        String ext = argv[0].substring(extIndex);  
        argv[0] = argv[0].substring(0, extIndex) + targetExtension;  
        File outputname = new File(argv[0]);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document [] document = new Document[argv.length];

        for(int i=1 ; i<argv.length ; i++)
            document[i] = builder.parse(fileList[i]);

        // Use a Transformer for output
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

        DOMSource [] source = new DOMSource [argv.length];
        for(int i=1 ; i<argv.length ; i++)
            source[i] = new DOMSource(document[i]);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream((File)outputname);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputStream);
        for(int i=1 ; i<argv.length ; i++)
            transformer.transform(source[i], result);

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
        // Error generated by the parser
        System.out.println("\n** Transformer Factory error");
        System.out.println("   " + tce.getMessage());

        // Use the contained exception, if any
        Throwable x = tce;

        if (tce.getException() != null) {
            x = tce.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        // Error generated by the parser
        System.out.println("\n** Transformation error");
        System.out.println("   " + te.getMessage());

        // Use the contained exception, if any
        Throwable x = te;

        if (te.getException() != null) {
            x = te.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sxe) {
        // Error generated by this application
        // (or a parser-initialization error)
        Exception x = sxe;

        if (sxe.getException() != null) {
            x = sxe.getException();
        }

        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        // Parser with specified options can't be built
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // I/O error
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} // main
}
```

Comment: I suspect that any remedy to this would take place in your Stylizer class, so please show us specifically what code you modified there.

Comment: OKAY THANK YOU VERY MUCH .I WILL NOW ADD THE ORIGINAL STYLIZER AND THE MODIFIED ONE,BECAUSE MY MODIFICATION IS SCATTERED HERE AND THERE

Comment: Ok, thank you for adding that. What is your expected result, though?

Comment: THE XML OUTPUT HAS MORE THAN ONE ROOT "request" is repeated four times.the first request is filled with my required output as you can see up in the page.I don't want the second and third and fourth "request".

Comment: Please stop typing in all caps. If you don't want the other three `request`s, then just specify one input file instead of four. :)  I'm assuming that's not what you really mean, so please specify what you want more clearly. Do you want one `<request>` containing the results of all four transformations?

Comment: Yes ! i want request to be one root

Answer (score 0):

You create a new file `outputname` by changing the name of the stylesheet file to end in `.xml`.

You use this file for a new `FileOutputStream` called `outputStream`.

Then you use this output stream for a new `StreamResult` called `result`.

Finally you transform each of your source XML files using the same result stream.

The transformer is doing as you have told it: it is transforming each DOM source independently and putting the results of each one in the same place.

It's not clear what you expect. Do you want the output combined into a single XML document somehow? If so then you must say *how* you want them combined.

Are you using four command-line XML files *as well* as the other two XML files that are in `document` calls in the XSLT stylesheet? Six XML files to be combined into one is an awful lot!

If you want four independent transforms then you will have to create four different output files and send the output of each transform to a different place.